# How to compare documents in the same collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I am a novice when it comes to mongo as I have traditionally only worked with Oracle database. 
I have a mongo database that's storing bitbucket data in columns like so:

```
_id | _class | collectorItemId| firstEverCommit | scmUrl | scmBranch | scmAuthor | scmCommitTimestamp
```

There are a few more columns in there that I've omitted for the sake of time. For the scmBranch column, the column is populated with one of two strings: "master" or "develop".
Here is a sample of what the data looks like:
[image]

Here is the document view of one of the rows:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e39d6a0330c130006a042c6"),
"collectorItemId" : ObjectId("5e33a6b9887ef5000620a0c0"),
"firstEverCommit" : false,
"scmUrl" : "sampleRepo1",
"scmBranch" : "master",
"scmRevisionNumber" : "a2ad6842468eb55bffcbe7d700b6addd3eb11629",
"scmAuthor" : "son123",
"scmCommitTimestamp" : NumberLong(1580841662000)
}
```

I am now trying to formulate mongo queries that will get me the following data:

```
 1. For each scmUrl, If max(scmCommitTimestamp) where scmBranch =
    "develop" > max(scmCommitTimestamp) where scmBranch = "master" THEN
    count the number of rows (i.e commits) where scmBranch = "develop"
    AND scmCommitTimestamp > max(scmCommitTimestamp) where scmBranch =
    "master"

 2. For the results found in #1, find the oldest commit and newest
    commit
```

So far, the best mongo query I've been able to come up with is the following:

```
db.bitbucket.aggregate([{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "scmUrl": "$scmUrl",
            "scmBranch": "$scmBranch"
        },
        "MostRecentCommit": {
            "$max": {"$toDate":"$scmCommitTimestamp"}
        }
    }
},{
    "$project": {
        "RepoName": {"$substr": ["$_id.scmUrl",39,-1]},
        "Branch": "$_id.scmBranch",
        "MostRecentCommit": "$MostRecentCommit"
    }
},{
   "$sort":{
       "RepoName":1,
       "Branch":1
       }

}
])
```

But this only gets me back the most recent commit for the develop branch and the master branch of each scmUrl (i.e repo), like so:
[image]

Ideally, I'd like to get back a table of results with the following columns:

```
scmUrl/RepoName | Number of commits on develop branch that are not on master branch| oldest commit in develop branch that's not in master branch | newest commit in develop branch that's not in master branch
```

How can I modify my mongo query to extract the data that I want?

Comment: this would be easy if you can sample docs & required o/p

Comment: @whoami I'm not sure what you mean here by sampling docs and required o/p.

Comment: @user3299259 : Few documents from your collection & final o/p you wanted to see

Comment: @whoami I've updated the question to provide sample data and a sample document. Hope my question is clearer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this.

Below query will grab the latest commit date from master for each repo. After you have the latest commit date you will join back to the same collection to pull all commits where branch is develop and has newer commits than master branch for each repo.

```
db.bitbucket.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"scmBranch":"master"}},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$scmUrl","recentcommitdate":{"$max":"$scmCommitTimestamp"}}},
  {"$lookup":{
   "from":"bitbucket",
    "let":{"scmUrl":"$_id","recentcommitdate":"$recentcommitdate"},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{"$expr":
        {"$and":[
          {"$eq":["$scmBranch","develop"]},
          {"$eq":["$scmUrl","$$scmUrl"]},
          {"$gte":["$scmCommitTimestamp", "$$recentcommitdate"]}
        ]}
      }},
      {"$sort":{"scmCommitTimestamp":-1}}
    ],
  "as":"commits"
  }},
  {"$match":{"commits.0":{"$exists":true}}},
  {"$project":{
     "commits":{"$size":"$commits"},
     "lastcommit":{"$arrayElemAt":["$commits",0]},
     "firstcommit":{"$arrayElemAt":["$commits",-1]}
  }}
])
```

Sample added here https://mongoplayground.net/p/wLnFY0H_nJz

**Update for revision ids**

```
db.bitbucket.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"scmBranch":"master"}},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$scmUrl","revisionIds":{"$push":"$scmRevisionNumber"}}},
  {"$lookup":{
   "from":"bitbucket",
    "let":{"scmUrl":"$_id","revisionIds":"$revisionIds"},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{"$expr":
        {"$and":[
          {"$eq":["$scmBranch","develop"]},
          {"$eq":["$scmUrl","$$scmUrl"]},
          {"$not":[{"$in":["$scmRevisionNumber","$$revisionIds"]}]}
        ]}
      }},
      {"$sort":{"scmCommitTimestamp":-1}}
    ],
  "as":"commits"
  }},
  {"$match":{"commits.0":{"$exists":true}}},
  {"$project":{
     "commits":{"$size":"$commits"},
     "lastcommit":{"$arrayElemAt":["$commits",0]},
     "firstcommit":{"$arrayElemAt":["$commits",-1]}
  }}
])
```

Comment: I ran this and it did not fetch any records even though I know there are develop branches that are ahead of master in my collection

Comment: Sorry, fixed the invalid reference and added a mongoplayground working link. Please try now.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've gone ahead and accepted this as the answer to my original question as it's helped a TON! However, how can I modify this query so that instead of going by timestamp, I make a set of all scmRevisionNumbers for each each repo on master. Then I do a lookup to pull all commits on develop where the scmRevisionNumber is not in the set I made.